# GraphServiceClient to create a new SharePoint Online Site

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to create a new subsite of another site in SP Online using the Graph SDK GraphServiceClient. I have successfully authenticated but I cant seem to get a site created - documentation is scarce as are examples so its basically hit and miss and I don't wish to use Graph REST for this purpose. Any help out there? The below code returns a Site object with an error of "invalid request". I'm sure I must be missing some required properties for the new Site object but which ones?

```
 ItemReference parent = new ItemReference();
 parent.Id = SiteRootForSubsite.Id;
 Site newSite = new Site
         {
            ParentReference = parent,
            Name = SubsiteName,
            WebUrl = "/documentcenter909/mynewsite"
        };

        Site createdSite = await _graphClient.Sites
            .Request()
            .AddAsync(newSite);
```

Comment: Unfortunately [you don't have the feature to create the site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) at this point as it only has Read only properties for the site. Being said that you can use the following workaround - can [create a office 365 group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), then assign owners & members a SharePoint Online site will be created automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately [you don't have the feature to create the site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0) at this point as it only has Read only properties for the site. Being said that you can use the following workaround - can [create an office 365 group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), then assign owners & members then you will see a new SharePoint Online site will be created automatically.

Comment: Thanks Dev I will give that a try and mark as Answer if it works

Comment: Sure @Laurence73!!

Comment: Seems you are correct Dev - graph doesnt allow site creation - seems there is an option to use the new Pnp framework here though - thanks again! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/provisioning-console-application-sample

Comment: You're welcome @Laurence73. Glad that the above helped :)